# R - creating rows based upon counter value

Tags: r

```
input <- read.table(header=F, text="abc 2 
                def 3 
                pq 2")
colnames(input) <- c("text","count")
```

I have input in terms of a text and the count of its occurrence in the data.
I am trying to get the output that will duplicate the text row the number of times the count is shown. I am struggling to find any function that can do it easily.

Expected output:

```
output <- read.table(header=F, text="abc 2 
                abc 2
                def 3
                def 3 
                def 3
                pq 2
                pq 2    ")
colnames(output) <- c("text","count")
```

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
as.data.frame(lapply(input, function(x) rep(x, input$count)))
#   text count
# 1  abc     2
# 2  abc     2
# 3  def     3
# 4  def     3
# 5  def     3
# 6   pq     2
# 7   pq     2
```

Comment: While it works it seems a little odd conceptually to repeat rows by repeating each column value.

Comment: @thelatemail, not sure what you mean. I think if you''ll break the code into parts you will get the logic. This was the first thing which came to my mind...

Comment: I get how this works, but see my answer that operates to just repeat rows using indexing. It gets around needing to repeat `rep` for each column of the dataset. If you're repeating rows, it seems to make sense to operate on rows not on columns.

Comment: @thelatemail, I have no doubt your answer is much more efficient. The problem is that I didn't think of it so couldn't post it :). But if you go all the way that path, we can also introduce a `data.table` solution, but I doubt this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(input)[, .SD[rep(1:.N, count)]]
 #   text count
 #1:  abc     2
 #2:  abc     2
 #3:  def     3
 #4:  def     3
 #5:  def     3
 #6:   pq     2
 #7:   pq     2
```

Or

```
  setDT(input)[input[,rep(1:.N, count)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use row indexing:

```
input[rep(seq(nrow(input)),input$count),]
# or even
input[rep(rownames(input),input$count),]

#    text count
#1    abc     2
#1.1  abc     2
#2    def     3
#2.1  def     3
#2.2  def     3
#3     pq     2
#3.1   pq     2
```

The second option works because you can index by the character vector in the `rownames` as well as `colnames`, e.g.:

```
rownames(input)
#[1] "1" "2" "3"
input["1",]
#  text count
#1  abc     2
```

Answer (score 0):

`by` should make quick work of this. Just process the input by row and then join it all up after:

```
output <- do.call(rbind, by(input, rownames(input), function(x) {
  data.frame(text=rep(x$text, x$count), x$count)
}))
rownames(output) <- NULL
colnames(output) <- c("text","count")
print(output)

##   text count
## 1  abc     2
## 2  abc     2
## 3  def     3
## 4  def     3
## 5  def     3
## 6   pq     2
## 7   pq     2
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I ended up using David's solution. Learnt a lot of different ways to achieve the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rep`

```
with(input, {
    data.frame(text = rep(levels(text), count), count = rep(count, count))
})
```

Or, use a helper function. Both returning the following. `inp` in the input data

```
f <- function(j, k) rep(j, k)
data.frame(text = inp$text[f(inp[,1], inp[,2])], count = f(inp[,2], inp[,2]))
#  text count
#1  abc     2
#2  abc     2
#3  def     3
#4  def     3
#5  def     3
#6   pq     2
#7   pq     2
```