# Dataframe reshaping based on column count

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2

I have a 2 column 100,000 row dataframe that looks as follows:

```
Count               String
3                 "Hello World"
2                  "Hi John"
1                  "Dear Joe"
```

I want to reshape this dataframe into a 1 column dataframe, removing the count and instead adding the repeating items. E.g.,

```
String 
"Hello World"
"Hello World"
"Hello World"
"Hi John"
"Hi John"
"Dear Joe"
```

Comment: An almost duplicate of ["creating rows based upon counter value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633942/r-creating-rows-based-upon-counter-value/)

Comment: See the [`expandRows` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/expandRows.R) from [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) :-)

Comment: `t(t(with(df, rep(String, Count))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
one_col_df <- data.frame(String = rep(df$String, df$Count))
```

What is going on there is that for each String, the function `rep` will repeat `Count` times, respecting their order in vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.

```
a <- c(3:1)
foo <- c("hello", "hi", "dear")

rep(foo, a)

[1] "hello" "hello" "hello" "hi"    "hi"    "dear"
```